# Is this function defined at zero?

Tags: real-analysis, arithmetic, definition, inverse

In the sense of real analysis, is this function defined at zero?

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{x}} = (x^{-1})^{-1}$$

Comment: WHY NOT? @Zduff

Comment: No. It's tempting to convert this expression to $f(x) = x$, but the identity $\frac{1}{\frac 1x} = x$ holds only for $x \neq 0$.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1616258/7090

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the multiplicative inverse of a real number $x$, denoted $x^{-1}$, is defined such that $x\cdot x^{-1} = 1$. There is the requirement that $0$ has no multiplicative inverse (otherwise we will have sacrificed some arithmetic nice properties). So we write $x^{-1} (= 1/x)$ if and only if $x \neq 0$. So the answer to your question is no.

It is very tempting to write $(x^{-1})^{-1} = x$ and to think that this applies to whatever real $x$ without recalling first that that we can write $x^{-1}$ for and only for $x \neq 0$.

Answer (score 1):

No it isnt, as without simplifying, you can't "straightfoward" plug in $0$. Simplifying assumes the denominator isn't zero and you get $f(x)=x$ for all $x\neq0$.  It's worth noting the function is tending to zero as $x\rightarrow0$ though.